# jquery hide forms on page

Tags: jquery, forms, filter, getelementbyid

Going around in circles with this can anyone help: i have a page the dynamically makes forms with id = form1, form2, form3, etc each form as a stop watch feature.

```
<form id="form183" action="" method="post" class="clockBtn">
<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="183" />
<input type="hidden" name="running" id="running" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="isRecord" id="isRecord" value="1" />
<button type="input" name="submit" id="timetrack" </button>
    </form> 


    <form id="form184" action="" method="post" class="clockBtn">
    <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="184" />
    <input type="hidden" name="running" id="running" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="isRecord" id="isRecord" value="1" />
    <button type="input" name="submit" id="timetrack" </button>
        </form> 

    <form id="form3" action="" method="post" class="clockBtn">
    <input type="hidden" name="running" id="running" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="isRecord" id="isRecord" value="1" />
    <button type="input" name="submit" id="timetrack" </button>
        </form>
```

so when i submit form to self the stopwatch starts with the id of the form that was submitted. What I am after is away that the rest of the forms get a class of display none until the submit button is pressed again to stop the stopwatch. When it is stop I would like the forms to be displayed again.

So what i was thinks is get the form elementById form (id="form123" ) the form submitted then adding  ( <> then filter) which adds  a class to the rest of the forms  display none. until the form is submitted again

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery to handle button click (if you update the html, i would apply a class to the button so you can select it by class since it is repeated) then you could go

```
$('.bntClass').click(function(e){ // something });
```

To your current rendered HTML

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
       var targetForm = $(this).parent();
       var nonParentForms = $('form').filter(function(){
          return $(this) != targetForm;
       });
       nonParentForms.toggle();
});
```

[Toggle API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Can not get it to work. could you setup up a jsfiddle please so i can see how to implement it thanks jon @WCEM2040

Comment: sure can.  can you look at the console and see what isn't working if it throws any errors.  getting fiddle now.

Comment: Your HTML was rendered a little bit incorrect. - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EricM280/33wLeLh8/1/)

Comment: Thank for does what i am after but does not work with my could added a fork to fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytx0mvb9/2/)  i need the form to submit so the result get stored in mysql can you take a look and see what you think cheers jon @WCEM240

Comment: @WCEM240 Thanks for the help got it working had to change `$('input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) to $('.clockBtn').on( 'click', '#timetrack', function (e)`Thank you